# How to setsubject in base64 encoding in mimemessage

Tags: encoding, jakarta-mail

While i send mail using javamail API i set the subject likr this

msg.setSubject(subject,charset);

But this setsubject method encode subject only in Quoted-printable encoding.
But i want to setsubject in base64 encoding.

For Example:

Expected result:  =?big5?B?............?=

result obtained:  =?big5?Q?.............?=

please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can encode and set subject header explicitly:

```
message.setHeader("Subject", MimeUtility.encodeText("Тема.", "utf-8", "B"));
```

Result:

```
Subject: =?utf-8?B?0uXs4C4=?=
```

But notice, that if your subject has only ASCII characters, it will NOT be encoded.

```
message.setHeader("Subject", MimeUtility.encodeText("Subject.", "utf-8", "B"));
```

Result:

```
Subject: Subject.
```